# android random number problem

Tags: android

Tried to create a random method that would query the database, obtain the number of rows in the database, and then grab a random number between 1 and the total number of rows to fetch a specific item in the database.  It works alright, but not great, if there are less than ten entries in the database it will repeat the same entry about 4 out of ten times.  I think I need a lead on a better method.

```
 number = mDbHelper.getCount(mDbHelper.mDb);
 Random generator = new Random(); 
 n = generator.nextInt((int) number);
 if(n <= 1){
   n = 1;
 }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, your database query is 1's-based.  Java `nextInt` is 0's-based, that is, `.nextInt(10)` will generate a random number between 0 and 9.  So your proper solution is to change line 3 to

```
n = generator.nextInt((int) number) + 1;
```

this will then give you what you need.

Because at present you are converting both [0] and [1] into 1 in lines 4 & 5, you are skewing your probability distribution.  Your first entry is going to get counted twice.  If you have an average of 5 entries in your `database`, this would give you the `2/5 = 40%` hit rate you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would try moving the line:

```
Random generator = new Random();
```

To your class's constructor or some other place where it will only get created once.  That should definitely help.

Other than that, the answers to this question might help you out:
[How good is java.util.Random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453479/how-good-is-java-util-random)

Comment: I do have the random function in the class constructor.  I am looking over the answer the you posts, there is a lot of information in there.