# Java - Generate a random -1 or 1?

Tags: java, random

Does anyone have a quick way to randomly return either 1 or -1?

Something like this probably works, but seems less than ideal:

```
return Random.nextDouble() > .5 ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: What's wrong with that ?

Comment: you're asking for ideal solutions when working with random numbers? ;)

Comment: `Random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1`

Comment: `return -1; // randomly chosen`

Comment: @mre : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453479/how-good-is-java-util-random/454433#454433

Comment: @Mike: seeing Bozho's answers I can certainly see what's wrong with *nextDouble() > .5 > 1 : -1*.

Answer (score 33):

how about:

```
random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1;
```

where `random` is an instance of `java.util.Random`

Comment: +1 Because this is the simplest of all the answers (some are really clever). However, just want to add that it is likely that *the same Random instance* should generally be used instead of always creating a new one ... otherwise leads to interesting "duplicate values" in degenerate situations.

Comment: @pst agreed on that. I just wanted to fit it on one line. I'll remove the instantiation.

Comment: Warning: you don't want to code this line inside a loop, it would not work! A single random object should be created outside.

Comment: @leonbloy just addressed that. The example was simplified, now it's more complete.

Comment: Just remember that `java.util.Random` class generates poor quality random numbers. It is suitable only for "casual" use.

Comment: "poor quality" is relative. For most typical uses it's ok. For critical applications, it's not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453479/how-good-is-java-util-random/

Answer (score 2):

```
return Random.nextInt(2) * 2 - 1;
```

Comment: @JustinKSU: No it wouldn't. The `nextInt` produces 0 or 1, which doubles to 0 or 2, which then becomes -1 or 1. The `nextInt` value is exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

`new Random.nextInt(2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: nextInt(integer) is between 0 (inclusively) and int (exclusively). thus you need Random.nextInt(2)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Random r = new Random();
n = r.nextInt(2) * 2 - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return Math.floor(Math.random()*2)*2-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;
```

public class RandomTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(randomOneOrMinusOne());

    }
}
static int randomOneOrMinusOne() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    if (rand.nextBoolean()) return 1;
    else return -1;
}
```

}