# Generate random number using longer seed in java

Tags: java, random

So I know I can call `random(long val)` in Java to generate a random number with a seed of 2^63.  How would one do better (larger seed value)?  I'm assuming this would have to be a manual class to perform such an accomplishment, but I'm a little lost as how to begin.

Comment: What do you want to make "better"? "Better randomness" can be had with SecureRandom.

Comment: Ahh, I was not aware of this library.  LEt me look up an example of how to use it.  Do you know what its limits are?

Comment: So I'm a little confused as how large the default seed is with SecureRandom.  If my random number is created using the following code 'Random ranGen = new SecureRandom();', how big is the seed?

Comment: See: [Neil Coffey's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/48933/neil-coffey) answer to ***[How good is java.util.Random?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/453554/1164465)*** and the ***[SecureRandom documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to increase the amount of seed material are:

- use an RNG designed to accept a lot of seed material.
- combine two different RNGs.

For the first, look at some of George Marsaglia's methods, which use arrays to hold their state.  There is an example at http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/10/05/george-marsaglias-random-number-generators/ (be careful to note the correction in the comments:

```
#define SHR3  (jsr^=(jsr<>17), jsr^=(jsr<<5))
```

The array t[256] is where most of the seed is held.

For the second, look at Pierre L'Ecuyer's work, for example, [Efficient and Portable Combined Random Number Generators](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/cacm88.pdf)