# Randomness of shuffled cards

Tags: java, arraylist, random, playing-cards

I have an Array List of cards containing 52 cards. I want to shuffle the deck.

This is what I have done.

1. Created a new Array List.
2. Generated random index between 0 to deck size.
3. Get card at random index and add to new list.
4. Remove card from deck
5. Repeat until deck is empty.

Here is my code:

```
String[] Number = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
String[] Suits = {"Club","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades"};
ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

// create a deck    

for(int i=0;i<13;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            Card card = new Card(Suits[j],Number[i]);
            deck.add(card);
        }    
    }

// shuffle of deck

ArrayList<Card> new_deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    while(deck.size()!=0){   

        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n = rand.nextInt(deck.size());

        new_deck.add(deck.get(n));
        deck.remove(n);
    }

// Display

for(int i=0;i<52;i++){
        System.out.println(new_deck.get(i).getSuit()+" : "+new_deck.get(i).getValue());
    }
```

Finally, I get the shuffled deck from new ArrayList.

Is its randomness good enough or not?

What should I do to increase randomness?

Comment: Is there any particular requirement about Randomness? Why do you feel that randomness is enough or not enough?

Comment: There is no such requirement but I have used custom method for shuffle this is main reason. hopefully you understand

Comment: You haven't effectively used custom method as underlying, it is java.util.Random. You should consider reading, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html   and   https://blog.tradeshift.com/sources-of-randomness-in-java/

Comment: size of deck changing every loop so I think this is custom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How good is java.util.Random?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453479/how-good-is-java-util-random)

Comment: I have used custom method after generating random number between 0 to n. That's the reason I have asked for some suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it's randomness is enough or not ?

Define *good enough* (!!)

Your current approach is going to give a good shuffle, with no obvious biases ... **except** for biases that may be introduced by the random number generator.

And in this case, there is real cause for concern.  Random is specified to be a linear congruential generator, and LC generations have distinct patterns in the numbers that they generate.  (In statistical terms, they show strong auto-correlation.)  This is quite clear if you graph the n'th random number against n.

To improve randomness, you should use a better random number generator.  The `SecureRandom` generator should be good enough: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html).

---

The same concern about the randomness applies if you use `Collections.shuffle` method.  For a *good* (or consistent) shuffle you should use the method overload where you supply a `Random` implementation ... and choose a good one.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you can simply use [Collections.shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) as shown below rather than reinventing the shuffling logic which is already provided by `Collections` API:

```
Collections.shuffle(deck);//Pass your ArrayList<Card> object i.e., deck
```

So, by reusing this existing `Collections` API clears all your doubts on the randomness of your `deck` object.

Comment: This takes away the burden of the randomness and delegates it to the API, is pretty fun to look at the implementation of it http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#455 and the comment "All permutations occur with equal likelihood assuming that the source of randomness is fair.
"

Answer (score 1):

You should define your notion of "randomness" in a precise way. "Increasing randomness" is a rather vague term.

I will assume by "random", what you want is a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) of [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) on your deck. Which is to say, you want your deck to be reordered in such a way that the chance that the next card is a particular card is equal.

There are two different factors at play here:

- How you shuffle
- How good a random generator `Random` is

---

#### How you shuffle

As far as how you shuffle goes, it is uniform. It can be proven by [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) that any card being in any position is exactly 1/52.

#### How good `util.Random` is

First, to be clear, `util.Random` is **not** actually random. It is a [pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)(PRNG). That means what they do is not to produce truly random numbers. Instead they *try* to, and depending on application requirements, it will be enough.

`util.Random` is a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), and as far as PRNGs go, its pretty weak. If you don't care about *really* randomizing your deck, it will work fine. However if you need something more robust, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453479/how-good-is-java-util-random) is a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue not mentioned here about `java.util.Random`: whether it can choose all permutations of a 52-item list. This is based on the number of seeds it admits. In general, a pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) can't choose more permutations of random number sequences than the number of seeds it admits (see "Shuffling" in my [article on randomness](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html) for further discussion). Nothing is said here about PRNGs that admit as many or more seeds than the number of permutations or whether the permutations the PRNG *can* choose have an equal probability of occurring, as opposed to an ideal process of generating *perfectly* independent uniform random integers.

`java.util.Random` admits no more than 2<sup>48</sup> seeds, since it uses a 48-bit seed length. However, there are 52-factorial permutations of a 52-item list, and that's higher than 2<sup>225</sup> -- which exceeds this maximum number of seeds by many orders of magnitude. Because of this, there are many, many permutations of a 52-item list that `java.util.Random` can't generate (using the same shuffling technique). (And this applies to *any* PRNG that admits fewer than 52-factorial seeds, not just linear congruential generators, like `java.util.Random`, in particular.) Therefore, an application that needs to shuffle a 52-item list would be well advised to avoid PRNGs that admit fewer than 52-factorial seeds (although even if a PRNG admits as many or more than 52-factorial seeds, that is not enough, by itself, to ensure the PRNG can choose from among all permutations with equal probability).

---

EDIT: Two recent questions discussed how to generate enough randomness to shuffle a digital "deck" of 52 cards:

[Is java.util.Random really that random? How can I generate 52! (factorial) possible sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771206/is-Java-util-random-really-that-random-how-can-I-generate-52-factorial-possi)

[Where can I get a reliable source of entropy (real randomness byte[])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787428/where-can-I-get-a-reliable-source-of-entropy-real-randomness-byte)

See the linked questions for details, and see also my section on [nondeterministic sources and seed generation](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Nondeterministic_Sources_and_Seed_Generation).

EDIT (Aug. 31, 2023): Edited.