# Where can I get a reliable source of entropy (real randomness byte[])?

Tags: java, android, random, random-seed, secure-random

Currently, I'm looking for a way to increase the *quality of randomness* in my `Android` application (a card game). Previously, it was estimated that for my situation (52! permutation) at least 226 bits of entropy (226 random bits) are needed..

I'm planning to use this `byte[]` as a seed for `SecureRandom`:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
random.setSeed(/* insert seed here, byte[] */)
```

**The question is** -- Where can I reliably get random bits in this amount (at least 226 bits) on `Android`, preferably without requiring any permissions and without internet. Also, it should work regardless of device and API level.

Comment: Please, don't repeat the android **tag** in the **title**.

Comment: *"...preferably without requiring any permissions and without internet..."* I very much doubt you can. You'd need permissions to use the mic to pick up ambient noise, for instance, or internet to use `random.org` or similar...

Comment: @KlingKlang - But I'm looking for an answer specifically for Android. Is this not correct to state it in the title?

Comment: NO. The **tag** is enough.

Comment: @KlingKlang - Alright, thank you for your guidance..

Comment: probably stupid, but what about two instances of `UUID.randomUUID().toString().getBytes();`?

Comment: My pleasure....

Comment: I guess, this is practically irrelevant for a game. One would have to play billions of games before seeing a repetition.

Comment: `SecureRandom` uses `/dev/random` on Linux and most likely Android.

Comment: @Eugene - That will be pseudo-random, not real entropy.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good point! thank you

Comment: What's the point of having "real" randomness? Especially in a game (related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426821/what-type-of-random-number-generator-is-used-in-the-casino-gaming-industry )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Java 8+ you can use

```
SecureRandom rand = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
```

To get the strongest randomness available on your platform.  To be explicit you can use

```
SecureRandom rand = SecureRandom.getInstance("NativePRNGBlocking");
```

which use the entropy of `/dev/random` on Linux like systems. However, I expect it will fail if not available.

https://www.synopsys.com/blogs/software-security/proper-use-of-javas-securerandom/

---

Alternatively

You could create randomness based on the user's input by taking a SHA256 or higher of the `System.nanoTime()` of previous events.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to access the mic (which would require permissions) or grab bytes from `random.org` (which would require internet), the only thing that I can think of is the user him/herself: Present a blank square the user moves their finger across, instructing them to do it as randomly as possible, ideally for several seconds, and use that touch data. (I seem to recall an app I used to use — TrueCrypt? — did this.) You might even throw some pseudo-randomness on top of their human-randomness to try to avoid people gaming the system with extraordinarily precise repeatable movements.

If you relax your requirements a bit, you can probably get some quite good entropy from the mic (ambient noise) and/or accelerometer. And of course, if you request network access, you can download truly random data from http://random.org.

Comment: If they don't care about permissions, getting a byte stream from the mic or ACCELEROMETER data, then adding that to a pseudo random number would seem to work well.

Comment: Very nice point, perhaps I could generate random bytes based on the actions in the previous round of the game..